# Connect To Redshift VPC C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, amazon-web-services, npgsql, amazon-redshift

Not to come off as a total idiot here.  I'm a .NET SQL Server guy trying to programmatically connect to AWS Redshift through C# for the first time and am having an impossible time getting a connection. I honestly dont know a lot about AWS so perhaps this is really obvious as to what my problem is.  Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Npgsql;

public class Redshift
{

    private readonly NpgsqlConnection _connection;

    private string _connectionString
    {
        get
        {
            NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.Host = "xxx.xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com";
            builder.Port = 5439;
            builder.UserName = "xxxx";
            builder.Password = "xxxx";

            return builder.ConnectionString;
        }
    }


    public Redshift()
    {
        _connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString);
        _connection.Open();
    }


}
```

Whenever I instantiate Redshift, I get:

Failed to establish a connection to 'xxx.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com.

Setting the inbound rule of the default VPC Security Group to accept All Traffic 0.0.0.0/0 didnt make a difference.

Comment: Test with `psql`. When you're connecting OK with `psql`, then test your code. At a guess your VPC entry node isn't routing traffic to the DB server; with VPC, it's impossible to usefully help you w/o a description of the network topology.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently, try to set both inbound and outbound rules for the security group and you should be fine.